# Listview tap event on iPad

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently building a mobile site for iPad using jquery mobile and ASP.NET MVC 4.  I have a dynamically created listview that is displaying search results.  I want the user to be able to click on an item in the listview and have the text from that particular list item appear in a textbox that is also in the view.

I can get this to work in Safari on my desktop machine, but it will not work on an iPad.

For the sake of simplicity and to attempt to narrow down the problem, I hard-coded a simple little listview in my View.  The results were the same.  Works on desktop in Safari, but not on iPad.

Here is the very simplified VIEW code that works in Safari on desktop (Please note that _Header is a separate, partial View):

```
@section Header
{ 
      <script type="text/javascript">

         $('#testJs li').on('click', (function () {    
            var results = $.trim($(this).text());         
            $('#testText').val(results);         
          }));

      </script>

      @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Header"); } 
}

@section Content 
{ 
     <input type="text" id="testText"> 
     <ul id="testJs" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">        
        <li id="task400" class="tasks">Test task 400</li>
        <li id="task295" class="tasks">Test task 295</li>          
     </ul>
}
```

**Please note that I have tried changing 'click' to 'tap' (see below) with no success.  It still doesn't work on iPad.**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#testJs li').on('tap', (function () {
        var results = $.trim($(this).text());         
        $('#testText').val(results);     
    }));

 </script>
```

I've also tried using the following with the same results.  Still doesn't work on the iPad.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#testJs').delegate('li', 'tap', function () {
        var results = $.trim($(this).text());         
        $('#testText').val(results);
    });

</script>
```

I do wonder if this has something to do with our use of layout pages.  We have slightly different layout pages, depending on if the site is being rendered on a mobile device or not.

Mobile Layout View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/mobileCss", "~/Content/css") 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> 
            @if (IsSectionDefined("Header")) {
                @RenderSection("Header", false) }
             else { <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1> }
        </div>  
        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderSection("Content")       
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Desktop Layout View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/mobilecss", "~/Content/css") 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b"> 
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> 
                @if (IsSectionDefined("Header")) {
                    @RenderSection("Header") }
                 else { <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1> }
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                @RenderSection("Content")
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days, so any help would be appreciated.  Everything I try works on my desktop, but not on an iPad - which is where I actually need it to function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using bind on your testJs li? I'd bind a tapHandler like below:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $( "#testJs li" ).bind( "tap", tHandler );

  function tHandler( event ){
        var results = $.trim($(this).text());         
        $("#testText").val(results);   
  }
});
</script>
```

or with on like this should work:

```
$('#testJs').on('tap', 'li', function (event) {
    var results = $.trim($(this).text());         
    $("#testText").val(results); 
     console.log('this should work')  
}
```

Also used double quotes on top example but that shouldn't make a difference I don't think. If it doesn't then make sure you .js references are correct, and use firebug in firefox to debug for any straggling errors.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked!  Thank you so so so much!  You just saved my work week man.  In case anyone else comes across this, I had tried your second suggestion (involving on) a few days ago while troubleshooting this myself and that didn't work on iPad either.  I had also tried switching between double quotes and single quotes with no success.  In any case, your first suggestion of .bind worked like a charm.  I'm having to learn jquery and MVC for the first time under tight deadlines on this work project, so I'm constantly learning from reading stackoverflow.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help bro! My last project was a .NET EF/MVC4 one and it was horrendous. I'm back to native iOS/Objective-C in my current project, but it's definitely not the last I've seen of jQuery, and .NET. iOS/Cocoa uses MVC extensively. Model View Controller is arguably one of the best paradigms around, regardless of platform. It helps promote modularization and collaboration, especially when you need to decipher your data and business logic from the view. You will carry your knowledge of it from platform to platform. Good Luck with your project!